# Emulating native iphone maps as a web app with location based service

Tags: iphone, maps, location

I'm wireframing an app quickly just to serve as a design mockup. I'm wondering if it is possible to emulate the location feature in the native apps map, specifically the blue pinpoint with the opaque perimiter eminating from it. I've visited the google maps mobile site, but the location button doesn't pin point your location precisely nor does it show any indication of doing so.

Answer (score -1):

As I was typing, I realized it does do exactly what I want. Just enable Wi-Fi and it shows an indicator, a perimeter, and zooms in street level. Wonderful. If you're on a weak 3G signal it won't pin point your location.